# Azure ARM DataFactory InvalidTemplate the runAfter property not valid; scope must belong to same level

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Documenting here what I learned, in case it helps someone else. I had a ARM template implementing a DataFactory pipeline, which had a weird InvalidTemplate error. I am simplifying my template to a contrived bare bones template,

```json
    resources: [
    {
        "name": "blah",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Foo",
                    "type": "SetVariable",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "variableName": "hi",
                        "value": {
                            "value": "int(1)",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "CoolIf",
                    "type": "IfCondition",
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "expression": {
                            "value": "@bool(equals(variables('hi'), 1))",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "ifTrueActivities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Blarg",
                                "type": "SetVariable",
                                "dependsOn": [{"activity": "Foo"}],
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "variableName": "okay",
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "@string(1 + int(variables('hi')))",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                        "ifFalseActivities": []
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
    }
    ]
```

produced the error message

```
ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The template validation
 failed: 'The 'runAfter' property of template action 'BlargScope'
 is not valid: the action 'FooScope' must belong to same level as
 action 'BlargScope'. Available actions on same level: ''
```

I could not find a good answer online.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of trial and error I realized you can put a `dependsOn` in the `IfCondition` parent, so below, just moves the `dependsOn` from the child `Blarg` to the parent `CoolIf`. And then it started working =) .

```json
    resources: [
    {
        "name": "blah",
            "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "properties": {
                "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "Foo",
                    "type": "SetVariable",
                    "dependsOn": [],
                    "userProperties": [],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "variableName": "hi",
                        "value": {
                            "value": "int(1)",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "CoolIf",
                    "type": "IfCondition",
                    "dependsOn": [{"activity": "Foo"}],
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "expression": {
                            "value": "@bool(equals(variables('hi'), 1))",
                            "type": "Expression"
                        },
                        "ifTrueActivities": [
                            {
                                "name": "Blarg",
                                "type": "SetVariable",
                                "dependsOn": [],
                                "userProperties": [],
                                "typeProperties": {
                                    "variableName": "okay",
                                    "value": {
                                        "value": "@string(1 + int(variables('hi')))",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                        "ifFalseActivities": []
                    }
                }
                ]
            }
    }
    ]
```

In retrospect I feel silly how simple this was haha.

Comment: I am getting similar error . my error happens if i have a stored procedure activity on success of set variable activity  ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The template validation failed: 'The 'runAfter' property of template action 'start loggingScope' contains non-existent action: 'set master groupid Scope'

Comment: If there is trailing space in the  preceding activity name then also this non-existent action issue occurs with invalidtemplate , i removed the space and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if the preceding shape name has a trailing space.

Comment: you are correct , if there is space in the name of preceeding activity then you will get invalid template,